# Whats the best fingering for playing this bar on left hand on piano?

Tags: piano, fingering

I have tried several ways but all of them fell not so good to me. Can anyone suggest a fingering for it ?

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I recommend one of two fingerings, depending on your hand span:

1. Narrower: `5-2-1  3-2-1-2-3` (or `5-2-1  4-2-1-2-4`)
2. Wider: `5-3-2-1  2-1-2-3` (or `5-2-1 2-1-2-4`)

Answer (score 1):

This piece illustrates precisely WHY we practice 'scales and arpeggios'.   Are you fluent at playing 'E minor arpeggio, 2 octaves'?   Good.  That's what this is, with some notes missed out. So play the familiar pattern, just with some notes missed out.  The way I was taught that would be 5 (4) 2 1 4 2 1 2 4.

(If you learnt some other system of arpeggio fingering, use that. I believe some teachers take the E♭ major fingering pattern as standard for white-note arpeggios, 3 1 4 2 1 4 2.  If that's what you know, fine, do that.)

But I'm afraid that if you stumble through 'E minor arpeggio, 2 octaves' you're going to stumble through this too.

Answer (score 1):

I’d go for `5-2-1-4 2-1-3-1`. This has the advantage of landing the final note on the group on 1, which makes hitting the next low note easier.

In practice this would look like this: